# Optimize and reduce size of Union Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union, toad

My question is about how to optimize  and reduce size of a sql query. I want to join more than 20 multiple queries using UNION, it is giving me the correct result as per the below logic, but I  am looking for two things here

- something more efficient
- I already have 20 UNIONS in my query, and every month I have to add 2-4 UNIONS more which make this query very long so is there any way this query can be rephrased with less code

  ```
   Select 
   '343' As 'Manual ID',
   '24/07/2020' As 'Date',
   A.ID,
   O.Order_Name,
   C.Customer_Name,
   Q.Quantity
   From Shipper A
   Left Join Order O  A.ID = O.ID
   Left Join Customer C A.ID = C.ID
   Left Join Quantity Q Q.ID = C.ID
   where A.ID IN (1)

   UNION

   Select 
   '323' As 'Manual ID',
   '24/08/2020' As 'Date',
   A.ID,
   O.Order_Name,
   C.Customer_Name,
   Q.Quantity
   From Shipper A
   Left Join Order O A.ID = O.ID
   Left Join Customer C A.ID = C.ID
   Left Join Quantity Q Q.ID = C.ID
   where A.ID IN(2,3,4)
  ```

  and so on ...

Result

```
Manual ID | Date       | Shipper | Order Name | Customer Name | Qty
343       | 24/07/2020 |   1     |   order1   |      A        |  5
323       | 24/08/2020 |   2     |   order2   |      B        |  2
323       | 24/08/2020 |   3     |   order3   |      C        |  1
323       | 24/08/2020 |   4     |   order4   |      D        |  12
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to make the unions faster, other than to suggest that the `ID` columns of all tables involved have an index on it.  That is, I suggest trying to optimize the individual queries, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thanks TIm for your quick response , I have to copy the from UNION whenever a new shipper is added. I have more than 20 UNIONS which is making the query long and every week 1 or 2 UNIONS are added, any advise how this query can be rephrased

Comment: Sample data, the output you're expecting from that data, and a clearer explanation of the problem you're trying to solve would help.

Comment: Since the only variables between each union seem to be `Manual ID`, `Date` and `A.ID`, you could make a report table in which each row is one of those variations. Then create a single query that selects all the report table rows and outputs a string consisting of a final SQL query. This wouldn't make the final query any more efficient, but it would make the process of creating the query more efficient.

Comment: How do you define the manual id, date is for a particular shipper id? Here in your example shipper id 1 is of date 24/07/2020 and manual id 343. How do you derive this?

Comment: kmoser - How to create a report table, could you please advise

Comment: Govind - Manual ID and date I get this information in an email from there I copy this and manually add to the sql query

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select
 CASE
    WHEN A.ID IN(1) THEN '343'
    WHEN A.ID IN(2,3,4) THEN '323'
 END As 'Manual ID',
 CASE
    WHEN A.ID IN(1) THEN '24/07/2020'
    WHEN A.ID IN(2,3,4) THEN '24/08/2020'
 END As 'Date',
 A.ID,
 O.Order_Name,
 C.Customer_Name,
 Q.Quantity
 From Shipper A
 Left Join Order O  A.ID = O.ID
 Left Join Customer C A.ID = C.ID
 Left Join Quantity Q Q.ID = C.ID
 Where A.ID IN(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: thanks, Soumendra but that would again be a length query

Comment: can you please share the result to see what went wrong ?

Comment: When I ran the query it showed me all the results from the database; as per requirements it should have shown me only for  AID - 1,2,3,4. Sorry can't share the results

Comment: Updating above comment: When I ran the query it showed me all the results from the database (900,000); as per requirements, it should have shown me only for  4 records AID - 1,2,3,4. Sorry can't share the results

Comment: Please consider voting up and accepting it if it solved the problem !

Comment: Thanks, Soumendra for the help, yes it solved the problem but still, I need to type AID 3 times. Is it possible that I have type once only

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to move the parameters in to another table, then join on it.  You can even make that an inline view if you don't want to use a real table...

Second suggestion is to use UNION ALL to avoid the costs of deduplication incurred by UNION.

```
SELECT
    params.*, 
    O.Order_Name,
    C.Customer_Name,
    Q.Quantity
FROM
(
              SELECT '343' As 'Manual ID', '24/07/2020' As 'Date', 1 AS A_ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '323' As 'Manual ID', '24/08/2020' As 'Date', 2 AS A_ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '323' As 'Manual ID', '24/08/2020' As 'Date', 3 AS A_ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '323' As 'Manual ID', '24/08/2020' As 'Date', 4 AS A_ID
)
  AS params
 INNER JOIN Shipper A ON A.ID = params.A_ID
 Left Join Order O ON A.ID = O.ID
 Left Join Customer C ON C A.ID = C.ID
 Left Join Quantity Q ON Q.ID = C.ID
```

Alternatively, don't recompute this every month. Write a new query each month, and insert the results into another table?

Comment: Thanks, MatBaillie, is it possible to add A_ID(2,3,4) together in one line instead of separate lines. Something like - SELECT '323' As 'Manual ID', '24/08/2020' As 'Date', 2,3,4 AS A_ID

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go for query the better way would be to use the case when statement but every now and then you need to keep updating the query adding new cases.

Another, optimized solution will be to create a new table to store
 `Manual ID, Date, (Common) ID` present in **Shipper** (Table). Then create a view to join all above tables with new Table.

**New Table**

```
Manual ID | Date       |   ID    |
343       | 24/07/2020 |   1     |
323       | 24/08/2020 |   2     |
323       | 24/08/2020 |   3     |
323       | 24/08/2020 |   4     |
```

Then Create a View Joining all Tables including new new table with **ID**.

In this you just need add new value to new table and you will complete result in view it self.

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW
AS
SELECT * FROM
(
 Select 
 T.[Manual ID],
 T.[Date],
 A.ID,
 O.Order_Name,
 C.Customer_Name,
 Q.Quantity
 From Shipper A
 Left Join Order O  A.ID = O.ID
 Left Join Customer C A.ID = C.ID
 Left Join Quantity Q Q.ID = C.ID
 Left Join NewTable T T.ID = A.ID
 )
```

Now just insert value in new table and fetch complete data from MY_VIEW. It will give the same result as you are excepting.

Comment: thanks Abhishek , is it possible to create the view in Excel and feed from there to this SQL query (in Toad) ?

Comment: yes it is possible to join multiple sheets same as of creating view. Checkout this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=325GKIXPsSI&t=40s .  And yes you can upload data from excel to sql through SSMS by "import" option.